# foreach loop used with Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary: `private static Dictionary<int, GameInfo> gameDictionary;` that contains instances of the `GameInfo` class, which itself contains the next dictionary `private Dictionary<int, PlayerInfo> playerDictionary;`

Now I want use a `foreach` loop to iterate over all items in `playerDictionary` for a specific game:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, PlayerInfo> item in gameDictionary[GAME_ID].)
{
}
```

How to do this without using the `public` modifier for `playerDictionary`?
`GameInfo` contains a second Dictionary, so I probably can't use an indexer.

Comment: If you don't want to use a public property you cannot access it. So i would suggest to use a private backing field but a public property. You could use an [Indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your field to a public property with a private setter:

From

```
private Dictionary<int, PlayerInfo> playerDictionary
```

to

```
public Dictionary<int, PlayerInfo> PlayerDictionary { get; private set;}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is process data where you have the visibility.

```
    public class GameInfo {
        private Dictionary<int, PlayerInfo> playerDictionary;

        static void ProcessPlayerInfo(Dictionary<int, GameInfo> gameDictionary, int gameNr = 1)
        {
            foreach (var key in gameDictionary[gameNr].playerDictionary.Keys)
            {
                var PlayerInfo = gameDictionary[gameNr].playerDictionary[key];
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can call it 'GameInfo.ProcessPlayerInfo(gameDictionary, 1);';

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to make a public method in GameInfo that loops over the playerDictionary. You can then call that using `((GameInfo)gamedictionary[Game_ID].value).PublicMethod()`.

Using this method means that you don't have code interacting with the playerDictionary outside of GameInfo, meaning your logic is separated better and you don't need to change multiple classes if you make a change to playerDictionary.

Comment: In `foreach` loop I need to use method from outside the `GameInfo` class. So `GameInfo` wont be independent class anymore. I think I will make `playerDictionary` as `public`.

Comment: In that case I think the best method would be the one suggested by vandango.